# How to split sql loop query into sections

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I have a database table `haccp` which holds rows of `criteria` categorised by 8 `sections`.
I'm trying to create a query to fetch all criteria and echo it under each section. For example:

**Section 1**

1. criteria 1
2. criteria 2

**Section 2**

1. criteria 1
2. criteria 2

I tried writing 8 separate sql queries using a `WHERE` clause and used a `while` loop to echo the results under each section but this took 30 secs to run and load the page.

**PREVIOUS SQL QUERY**

```
$get_delivery_criteria = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT criteria, section, hazard FROM haccp WHERE section='Delivery' ORDER BY criteria");
$get_delivery_criteria->execute();
$get_delivery_criteria->bind_result($criteria_db, $section, $hazard);
$get_delivery_criteria->store_result();
$row_cnt = $get_delivery_criteria->num_rows();
if($row_cnt >= 1)
{
    while ($get_delivery_criteria->fetch() )
    { 
    ?>
        <li><a href="?criteria=<? echo $criteria_db; ?>"><? echo $criteria_db. " ". $hazard; ?></a></li>    
    <? 
    }
    $get_delivery_criteria->close();
}
```

So i'm working on a new query that lists the sections in an `array` then uses `foreach` to loop through the criteria and display each under the section heading.

**NEW SQL QUERY**

```
$sections = array("1.Delivery", "2.Storage", "3.Preparation", "4.Cooking", "5.Serving", "6.Cleaning", "7.Building", "8.Management");
$get_criteria = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT criteria, section, hazard FROM haccp ORDER BY criteria");
$get_criteria->execute();
$get_criteria->bind_result($criteria_db, $section_db, $hazard_db);
$get_criteria->store_result();                              
$row_cnt = $get_criteria->num_rows();

if($row_cnt >= 1)
{
    while ($get_criteria->fetch() )
    { 
        foreach ($sections as $section)
        ?>
            <p class="haccp-section"><strong><? echo $section; ?></strong></p>
            <div class="divider"></div>
            <li><a href="?criteria=<? echo $criteria_db; ?>"><? echo $criteria_db. " ". $hazard_db; ?></a></li> 
        <? 
    }
}
$get_criteria->close();
```

However, this is echo'ing the section heading for each criteria, rather than the heading the the criteria list below.

Hope that makes sense and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

As I understand your issue. May be you want to group your data according to Section. For this try below code :

```
<?php
 $get_criteria = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT criteria, section, hazard FROM haccp ORDER BY section,criteria");

  $get_delivery_criteria->execute();
$get_delivery_criteria->bind_result($criteria_db, $section, $hazard);
$get_delivery_criteria->store_result();
$row_cnt = $get_delivery_criteria->num_rows();
if($row_cnt >= 1)
{
  $current_section="";
    while ($get_delivery_criteria->fetch() )
    { 

      if($section != $current_section)
      { ?>
        <p class="haccp-section"><strong><? echo $section; ?></strong></p>
        <div class="divider"></div>
      <?php 
        $current_section=$section;
      } ?>

      <li><a href="?criteria=<? echo $criteria_db; ?>"><? echo $criteria_db. " ". $hazard; ?></a></li>    
    <? 
    }
    $get_delivery_criteria->close();
}
```

Comment: That would mean I would have to specify the current section as a variable, and therefore do this for each section which would mean 8 variables and 8 queries. Which is what my first query was - I just used a `WHERE` clause to specify each section. I'm looking for one query really.

Comment: @user3464091 have you seen my entire solution ? I am not calling quey 8 times. Its only once. Please see answer properly

Comment: It doesn't work - returns `function fetch() on null in`. You're not setting `$section` from the array or the database?

Comment: `function fetch() on null in` is not issue of logic. Check your query executes proper or not

Comment: I have added only extra `ORDER BY` field which is `section` in your first attempt query. If your first query executed successfully then it must

Answer (score 0):

@B.Desai
I've tweaked your query to use `$section_db` which wasn't correct. This now works as expected:

```
                                    $get_criteria = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT criteria, section, hazard FROM haccp ORDER BY criteria");
                                    $get_criteria->execute();
                                    $get_criteria->bind_result($criteria_db, $section_db, $hazard_db);
                                    $get_criteria->store_result();                              
                                    $row_cnt = $get_criteria->num_rows();

                                    if($row_cnt >= 1)
                                    {
                                      $current_section="";
                                        while ($get_criteria->fetch() )
                                        { 
                                          if($section_db != $current_section)
                                          { 
                                          $current_section=$section_db;
                                          ?>
                                            <p class="haccp-section"><strong><? echo $section_db; ?></strong></p>
                                            <div class="divider"></div>
                                          <? 
                                          } 
                                          ?>
                                          <li><a href="?criteria=<? echo $criteria_db; ?>"><? echo $criteria_db. " ". $hazard_db; ?></a></li>    
                                          <? 
                                        }
                                        $get_criteria->close();
                                    }
```

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: BTW you only have change of variable i.e `$section` to `$section_db`. You are declaring array but I can's see that you have use that array in anywhere in your posted answer code

Comment: I don't understand how the `section` is echo'd only once from the `if` clause and not repeated in the loop though?

Comment: Yes, but I moved this line `$current_section=$section_db;` **before** the `<li>` as the variable wasn't been passed.

Comment: Its because of condition. It will only true when `section` is changed.

Comment: I see. Because `$current_section` is set outside of the `while` loop?

Comment: You had `$current_section=$section_db;` **after** the `<li>` statement so it wasn't been passed correctly. Once I moved these lines around it work ok.

Comment: No its before or after not affected. try to understand logic.`$current_section` will be use for next time of loop and also its not used in `<li>`.